# Why do I have parenthesis when I print strings plus variables in Python34?

Tags: python-3.x

**The code**

```
print("5 + 2 =", 5+2)
```

And the result I get is ('5 + 2 =', 7)

Comment: Are you sure it's Python 3.4 you are using and not Python 2?

Comment: Using python 3.4.3 print("5 + 2 =", 5+2) prints 5 + 2 = 7 for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You are using an interpreter for Python 2.

Python 2 output:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jul 20 2011, 02:32:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM, Emscripten 1.5, Empythoned)] on linux2
print("5 + 2 =", 5+2)
('5 + 2 =', 7)
```

Python 3 output:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
print("5 + 2 =", 5+2)
5 + 2 = 7
```